# IIS 6 Tuning Guide?

Tags: iis, optimization, iis-6

I have been a developer for 10+ years and so far my IIS knowledge is just enough for deploying stuff on it and get it running. Recently I have been playing with IIS 6 and realize the huge difference on the worker process model. I think I would need some good guide to update my knowledge in this area. Any good article/book recommendation?

Answer (score 5):

[IIS Tuner](http://iistuner.codeplex.com) is an open source tool for tuning IIS 6, 7 and 7.5

Answer (score 4):

There are several online resources, starting with this one:

[Performance Tuning (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/71490aae-f444-443c-8b2a-520c2961408e.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

[www.iis.net](http://blogs.iis.net/) - central place for everything related to IIS..

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this which I thought was very good: [Best practices for creating websites in IIS 6.0](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/04/best-practices-for-creating-websites-in-iis-6-0.aspx)

Comment: agree this is a good one. I read that already before this Q comes out, just want to see if there is something extensive.

Answer (score 0):

David Wang has some great articles on the inner workings of IIS6. For various reasons his blog was split over two sites:

http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/default.aspx

http://w3-4u.blogspot.com/

And...[Tess](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/about.aspx) who is a MS escalation engineer has some amazing articles on debugging and diagnosing badly behaved/perfoming apps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/default.aspx